# Read raw image file in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How to read Python image from string data imageData? I have tried Image.fromstring from PIL and numpy.frombuffer but it hasn't worked yet.

```
f = open('lena.bmp','rb')
imageData = f.read()
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to open a file not import data from a string.

Comment: It's a part of an open source project. The only way to get access to the file is through imageData.